# Finding intersection point using boost library

Tags: c++, boost, intersection, boost-geometry

I would like calculate an intersection point between some segment and box. Unfortunately I haven't found such function in the boost library.
I have something like this:

```cpp
using boost::geometry;
using Point = model::point<double, 3, cs::cartesian>;
using Box = model::box<Point>;
using Line = model::segment<Point>;

index::rtree<Box, index::quadratic<16>> rtree;

...

//EDIT
std::vector<std::vector<Point>> getIntersection(Line line){
    std::vector<Box> boxes;

    rtree.query(index::intersects(line), std::back_inserter(boxes));

    std::vector<std::vector<Point>> result;
    for(const auto&box: boxes){
        std::vector<Point> points;
        intersection(line, box, points); // can't compile
        result.push_back(points);
    }

    return result;
}
```

So you see I currently return all intersected boxes contained in the `rtree`.
Intersection detection works fine but I also need to know where it is.
Sadly I can't use vector of points at all.
Well, does anyone know how to get this point?

EDIT:

I've added `intersection` function. Now though I pass intuitively good arguments it doesn't compile. Looks like there's no solution because according to given error function isn't implemented for such types.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can further use your collected boxes and find intersection points with the function:

```
template<typename Geometry1, typename Geometry2, typename GeometryOut>
bool intersection(Geometry1 const & geometry1,
                  Geometry2 const & geometry2,
                  GeometryOut & geometry_out)
```

See an example in the [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/intersection.html)